# HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers

Tags: php, webservice, xampp, soap, nusoap

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una WebService usando NuSoapClient y me sale este mensaje:

> HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers

Libreria : https://github.com/Lawiet/nusoap

Estoy probando en servidor local XAMPP.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use lawiet\src\NuSoapClient;

$client = new NuSoapClient('https://ruta.pe/webservice.php');
$user = "USU";
$password = "PASS";
$client->setCredentials($user,$password);      
$dni = "87654123";
$result = $client->call('consulta', array('dni'=>$dni));
    if ($client->fault) {
        print_r($result['faultstring']);
    } else {
        $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    } else {
        print_r($result);
    }
}
exit;

?>
```

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto? ¿Es un error del código?, ¿Problema con mi servidor local?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a aumentar el valor de *memory_limit* en php.ini

Por defecto tiene un valor de 128M. Es muy probable que aumentarlo a 256M solucione el problema: `memory_limit = 256M`

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Un ejemplo con la directiva sería genial.

Comment: @Adrián Por defecto tiene un valor de 128M. Es muy probable que aumentarlo a 256M solucione el problema: `memory_limit = 256M`

Comment: Puede ser. Edita la respuesta y colócalo allí en lugar del comentario. Recuerda que las respuestas no sólo ayudan a quién pregunta sino a otras personas que puedan tener el mismo problema.